# What's wrong with this CNN framework construction?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

```
Anger_train = Anger_train.to_numpy().reshape(Anger_train.shape[0], 1, Anger_train.shape[1])
Anger_test = Anger_test.to_numpy().reshape(Anger_test.shape[0], 1, Anger_test.shape[1])
def getModel():
    
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv1D(64,1, activation='relu', input_shape=(941,1,43)))
    model.add(Conv1D(64,1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D())
    
    

    model.add(Flatten())
    
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="sgd")
    
    return model
```

where the input is 941 instances with 43  scalar features,  and the output is a continuous variable between 0 and 1. The error so far is

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer maxpooling1D is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 1, 43, 256)
```

Comment: Don't include the batch size in the input shape. The code you posted is also clearly not the code that actually produces the error...

Comment: As I changed the input_shape, now shown  Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 ....

Comment: Well that's because your input shape has one (1, single) time step. Why do you use convolution? This whole thing doesn't really make sense to me.